# In powershell how to output an ArrayList to CSV

Tags: powershell

I am trying to export an ArrayList object to a CSV file. The object is a list of 3 element arrays.

I have been trying something like the following however I just get information about the object (number of elements, length, etc).

`$CsvArrayList | Export-Csv "./Output.csv"`

Is it possible to output the values contained in an array list into csv format? Ideally one line per array and one element per cell.

Comment: You need to force your inner arrays to enumerate before sending to the CSV command. `$csvarraylist | foreach-object {$_} | export-CSV output.csv -notype`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create the CSV manually using `-join`, however this may be slow if there are lots of arrays:

```
$CSVArrayList = new-Object System.Collections.ArrayList

[void]$CSVArrayList.Add(@('1','2','3'))
[void]$CSVArrayList.Add(@('4','5','6'))

Set-Content "./Output.csv" -Value $null

Foreach ($arr in $CSVArrayList) {
      $arr -join ',' | Add-Content "./Output.csv"
}
```